# On the group of order 120

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a non-solvable group such that $|Z(G)|=2$.
If $G/Z(G) \cong A_5$, then can we conclude that $G \cong SL(2,5)$?

I use GAP and saw $G=SL(2,5)$. But i need to say a proof for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For instance, $G$ might also be $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \times A_5$. (This isn't the same thing as $SL(2,5)$, because in this case, $A_5$ would be a normal subgroup of $G$, whereas $A_5$ isn't a normal subgroup of $SL(2,5)$.)

Comment: That is the only other possibility for $G$.

Comment: @Billy Thanks for answer. If we assume that $G^{\prime}=G$ in my question, then $G \cong SL(2,5)$ by https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130491/about-the-non-solvable-group-of-order-120                                                                                        but i dont like that proof. is there another proof for this?

Comment: I assume you know that the only possible groups are $SL(2,5)$, $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times A_5$ and $S_5$? It's easy to see that  $(\mathbb{Z}_2 \times A_5)' < \mathbb{Z}_2 \times A_5$. And you can rule out the symmetric group by showing that $S_5' \leq A_5$. Hint: consider parity of commutators.

Comment: [link](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_120) Here's a proof sketch showing why those $3$ are the only non-solvable groups of order $120$.